# Peculiar behavior of NA values. Can anyone provide insight into understanding the mechanics?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

So, I have a dataframe with 90, 797 row and 29 columns, respectively, according to nrow(df) and ncol(df).

When using summary(df), I note that my dataframe contains NA values in 8 variables. The number of NA values across all columns are less than 15,000.

Why, then, when I run the following code, I return far fewer rows than 90,979 - 15,000.

nrow(df2[complete.cases(df2),]) # this returns 14,186 rows

I double-checked using the na.omit(df) function as well, and it also returned 14,186 rows. How is this possible?

BUT, the mystery deepens. When I use a variable with 5,597 NA values in a summary function with Dplyr, I am not getting an NA value returned, in spite of leaving them as is (not using na.rm = T).

Example, where variable Channel_1_qty contains over 5,000 NA values:

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
  select(Season, Article, Channel_1_qty) %>%
  filter(Season %in% c("FW2022", "SS2023") & (Channel_1_qty > 0)) %>%
  group_by(Season) %>%
  summarise(
    article_count = n_distinct(Article),
    tot_qty = sum(Channel_1_qty)
  )
```

This gives me the output that I want. However, if I filter the initial dataframe using complete cases or na.omit() first, I return far fewer rows than I do leaving them in. What is happening under the hood. It was my understanding that Dplyr could not return a summary statistic if NA values were included, or if it did, they would be removed from the dataframe.

Can anyone provide insight into what's happening? Sorry I cannot post the original data file or have a reproducible example. It's more theoretical / understanding what's happening "under the hood" in R.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to help without any data; my gut feeling is that your NAs are not really NAs. Compare `is.na("NA")` with `is.na(NA)`. Perhaps check for `"NA"` entries; and/or include minimal reproducible sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll try these tomorrow, and report the results + try to upload some sample data when I can.